# Name header for context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, image, contextmenu

The title seems easier than first thought, but I have a context menu that is bound to a list of items. I want to be able to display a title for the context menu to access the list. Currently it just shows up as blank and then allows me to view the list, however I need it to display a title "Add Existing Properties". Also if someone can help me with my image problem that would be much appreciated :). Instead of the first one having the image name I want that to display the name "Add Existing Properties"

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AddNodeTemplate">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#F7F7F7">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <DrawingBrush Viewport="8,8,8,8" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile">
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#F7F7F7">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryGroup>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50"/>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,50,50"/>
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="ButtonAdd" Click="ButtonAdd_Click" Height="30" Width="130">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Grid Background="#F7F7F7">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Image Source="Images/icon_plus.bmp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="Add Property" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="LightGray" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F7F7F7"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                    <Button.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Add Exisiting Properties" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableProperties}">
                                    <MenuItem.Resources>
                                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                                                
                                                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}" />
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="Icon">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel>
                                                        <Image Width="12" Height="12" Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter}}" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                    </MenuItem.Resources>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="Upscale well logs"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Upscale well_top attributes"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Upscale point attributes"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Calculate"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Button.ContextMenu>
                </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**What is displayed**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This style `<Style TargetType="MenuItem">` in fact ***also*** applies on the top level MenuItem (the one you hardcodedly set its `Header` to `Add Exisiting Properties`). You need to use a `Trigger` to filter that out based on the `Role` property. All the sub menu items have `Role` of `SubMenuItem`, so it should be like this:

```
 <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
     <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubMenuItem">
             <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                           <DataTemplate>
                             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                               <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                             </StackPanel>
                           </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
        </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
     <!-- ... -->
 </Style>
```

***Edit***: About the Icon, you explicitly set it to a `DataTemplate` which is not rendered, instead it uses the string returned by `ToString()` (hence the text `System.Windows.DataTemplate` in place of the icon). You can just remove `DataTemplate` like this:

```
<!-- define a non-shared resource of Image -->
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
   <Style.Resources>
      <Image x:Key="img" x:Shared="False" Width="12" Height="12" Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter}}" 
             Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
   </Style.Resources>
   <!-- ... -->
</Style>

<Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource img}"/>
```

***Final solution:***

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
     <Style.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
              <Style.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="ContentSource" Value="Icon">
                     <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                         <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                               <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                         </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                  </Trigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>   
     </Style.Resources>      
     <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon, 
             Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter}}"/>   
     <!-- ... -->
 </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks that was perfect :), do you know how to solve my image problem?

Comment: Thanks, it has worked but only for my last item in my context menu list do you know why?

Comment: @RyanArchibald looks like the `Image` is shared between MenuItem's Icon, so try defining it as a non-shared Resource (using `x:Shared`), see my modified code.

Comment: Still the same output :(

Comment: @RyanArchibald in fact I usually re-template the `MenuItem` so never encountered this before. The `Icon` is not part of `Header` and there is not any property exposed via `MenuItem` to style just the `Icon`. It's very tricky about that. We need to style the `ContentPresenter` which is what actually holds the Icon with `ContentSource` set to `Icon`. We simply re-template that. Anyway Microsoft designed this not very well. See my final solution (it has been tested).

Answer (score 0):

you can either use 
`

```
<MenuItem Header="Add Exisiting Properties" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableProperties}">
    <MenuItem.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
         <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
              <Setter.Value>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                                                  
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
                     </StackPanel>
                 </DataTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
```

`or`

```
<MenuItem Header="Add Exisiting Properties" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableProperties}">
            <MenuItem.Resources>
              <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                 <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <DataTemplate>
                         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                                                     
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Header}" />
                         </StackPanel>
                       </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                 </Setter>
```

`

Comment: Your second suggestion give gives me blanks for them :(, however the first one I'm getting an error just now that the header is not recognized or accessible